# Triviality of the tangent space of an abelian variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, abelian-varieties

The tangent bundle of an abelian variety $A/K$ is trivial. Mumford's proof of this fact goes something like this: given the (non-zero) value of a section in a fiber, one can determine the value in all of the fiber by the group law. This is the same as the proof for Lie groups.

But this seems somewhat incomplete to me, since in the algebraic geometry setting one specifies a section by stalks, rather than values in the residue field at each stalk. So my question is, how does one actually show that knowing all these values gives you a section with  those values?

Comment: Using the language of group schemes a general fact is that if $G/S$ is a group scheme and $f\colon G\to S$ is the structure morphism and $e\colon S\to G$ the unit section, then there is a canonical isomorphism $\Omega^1_{G/S}\simeq f^*e^*\Omega^1_{G/S}$. Now if $G/S$ is smooth then $\Omega^1_{G/S}$ is locally free and if $S$ is a field (more generally local) then $e^*\Omega^1_{G/S}$ is trivial and so is $f^*e^*\Omega^1_{G/S}$ which then shows that $\Omega^1_{G/S}$ is free.

Comment: I will probably post an answer to what Mumford means at some point in the future when I find time.

Comment: @S.S. : To your second comment, please do share. I look forward to your answer! :-)