# Tangent bundle of Jacobian of a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, tangent-bundle

In [An Introduction to the Theory of Special Divisors on Algebraic Curves](https://www.ams.org/books/cbms/044/cbms044-endmatter.pdf), Griffiths states that

> Obviously the tangent bundle of the Jacobian is trivial.

Why is this the case?

(Unfortunately, I don't have access to the entire book.)

Comment: Related (but unfortunately still without answers):  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339566/triviality-of-the-tangent-space-of-an-abelian-variety.  Related and with answers (but in the context of Lie groups):  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308691/let-g-be-a-lie-group-show-that-there-is-a-diffeomorphism-tg-cong-g-times-t/308798#308798.

Comment: It's an abelian variety so in particular a smooth group scheme and one can easily show that if $e\colon \operatorname{Spec}(k)\to A$ is the unit section and $f\colon A\to k$ the structure morphism then $\Omega^1_{A/k}=f^*e^*\Omega^1_{A/k}$. Now $e^*\Omega^1_{A/k}$ is trivial since it is a sheaf on a point.

Answer (score 5):

The Jacobian of a curve is a group scheme, it acts on itself transitively (by translations), and the tangent bundle is equivariant. In general, there is an equivalence between the category of equivariant vector bundles on a homogeneous space of a group scheme and representations of the stabilizer of a point. In the case of the Jacobian the stabilizer is trivial, hence any its representation is trivial, hence any equivariant vector bundle is trivial. In particular, so is the tangent bundle.